# Карамелизованный или карамелизированный?

Tags: словообразование, грамматика, орфоэпия

Как правильно -  карамелизованный(ая) или карамелизированный(ая)?

Comment: Карамелизированный, да так и не карамелизованный :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Словарь синонимов, единственный словарь, где представлены два варианта. В кулинарном же словаре есть "Карамелизировать". Прилагательное от этого глагола карамелизированный.

Дело в том, что в русском языке глаголы с суффиксами - изирова -, -изова варьируются: ***стандартизировать — стандартизовать, колонизировать — колонизо
вать.*** Соотношение их в русском языке исторически менялось, у ряда глаголов варианты с суффиксом ***- изирова - архаизовались и теперь используются
только более короткие: локализовать, мобилизовать, материализовать,
нормализовать, парализовать.*** ***У иных же варианты с суффиксом - изова - устарели: канонизовать, конкретизоватъ. С суффиксом - изирова - закрепились глаголы : иронизировать, симпатизировать, гипнотизировать и др.***

В кулинарном словаре, очевидно, закрепился более длинный вариант: ***"карамелизированный".***

Перевод и русская грамматика: Учебно-методическое пособие для вузов
Автор/создатель: Ильина Т.В., Швецова О.А., Ломова Т.М.
Год: 2008